# React Native: How to place the text block at the end of line

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to place the text block at the end of line and wrap if need, like this:

[image]

I'm trying so much but it doesn't work, here's my code:

```
<View style={{
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
}}>
  <Text>React native text 1</Text>
  <Text>React native text 2</Text>
  <Text>React native text 3</Text>
</View>
```

And my result:

[image]

Is there any way I can achieve this, plz. Thanks

Comment: what do you currently see? did you try putting a width of 100% on the View?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to encapsulate Text in parent Text component? Like

```
<View style={{
  //flexDirection: 'row', //no more needed
  //flexWrap: 'wrap', //no more needed
}}>
  <Text>
    <Text>React native text 1</Text>
    <Text>React native text 2</Text>
    <Text>React native text 3</Text>
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to use the nested Text, because `onLayout` and `.measure` doesn't work for nested Text

Comment: Yeah I see! But you can use it on View parent which have almost same coordinates than his Text children.

Comment: This is just a sample, Actually my View's children contain many Text element, so I want to know the position of each